# Scheduled restart with webJob @azure

Tags: azure, chatbot, restart

I want to use a webJob (found no other option) to restart my chatBot every day at noon.

Everything I found online only works with a "Service Principal Id", but you need to be a global admin to get one. Is there any possibility to do a scheduled restart without webJobs / Service Principal Id?

I am the owner of the subscription and the app service I want to restart, but no Azure AD global admin due to company restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use Web Jobs for that, there is a better option.

You should be able to create a **time-triggered Azure Functio**n with [Managed Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) (formerly known as MSI). Then you can assign e. g. Contributor rights to that Azure Function Instance for your ChatBot.

**Note:** Managed Identity will internally also create a special type of service principal. But this principle is managed by Azure.

Further reading:
[How to use managed identities for App Service and Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet)

Comment: Do you think logic apps are working too? Because of your suggestion with functions I found them and they seem to be easier to care for.

Comment: Probably yes, see this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/restart-azure-web-app-using-azure-logic-app).

Comment: I found no way to get this running with logic apps, but funtions just work fine after a bit of trying.

Comment: Hey @BeschtPlaier,
Is your ChatBot happen to be a WebJob? Please share your code if that is the case. Am trying to have a Azure Function stopping and starting my continuous WebJob but only found info on how to 'run' a triggered WebJob.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, No my chatbot is no WebJob, sorry